# Android Ripple Drawable Error on Pre-Lollipop Devices - Android SDK 25

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am a newbie to both Android Programming and StackOverflow. This is my first question, however I have used the StackOverflow platform before for solutions here and there. Now, to my question. I have an Android app that used to run fine on all android devices from SDK 11. However, on an update to SDK 25 it crashes on pre-lollipop devices.

My log cat is as follows:

```
Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

I have included `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in my gradle. My `minSdkVersion = 11`, `targetSdkVersion = 25`, `supportLibraryVersion = 25.2.0`

I have tried all the suggestions I could find here but none works. So please guys I need your help. I am eager to learn so that I can fix this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Which gradle version are you using?

Comment: I am using Gradle Version 3.3 and Plugin Version 2.3

Comment: It is correct. Could you just share the project by removing all the other code except trying to reference to that image which causes this exception

Comment: The code is on a BitBucket and I can't exactly pinpoint the image causing the error. In my drawable folder I have XML selectors which change the image on focus or change. Then the rest of the images are PNGs. I can send you an invite if you have a BitBucket account. Thanks.

Comment: You can send request to singh_anurag.

Comment: @AnuragSingh its done, you should be able to read the code.

Comment: Is there a way we can chat in real time so that we can be able to resolve this faster. The activity in question is RecentActivityActivity. Am available on Skype as victorokech

Comment: Sorry for replying lately. I Invested around three hours for just to figure what the problem is. vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true has nothing to do as you are not using any vector files. If I change RecentActivityActivity extends ClikChatActivity to RecentActivityActivity extends AppCompatActivity with some code commenting then everything works fine. So the problem is in ClikChatActivity. I did comment our most of the code but still not able to exactly figure out which line is leading to crash.

Comment: One strange behaviour if I make RecentActivityActivity as the launcher activity and don't make any changes. The first launch will crash but not the second one. 3rd launch crashes but not the fourth one. So alternate launches are successful. It used to be platform bug which google had fixed in previous releases. Still looking or working upon this. I am sorry for not able to solve your problem in time.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, thanks for helping me out. Its quite funny coz if you run the app on a device with Android M then it does not crash when you launch the app. Initially before I did the update to the latest version of Android, I didn't have this problem. Thanks again, am just glad you are helping out. This problem has really given me a headache.

Comment: I can understand your pain. It's just that I am quiet busy but I will be debugging more into it tomorrow.

Comment: I understand. I will await your feedback. I will also keep trying on my end based on the insight you have provided on ClikChatActivity. Thanks.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, I figured out the problem. I will post my solution, however it is not relevant to the Ripple Drawable as I earlier thought. Thanks for your help my friend.

Comment: You are welcome Victor. I am happy to know that you have resolved the issue. Will wait for the solution for this mysterious problem. Well what was the problem exactly?

Comment: Hello @AnuragSingh, the issue was actually with Android permissions. When I updated my code to work with permissions I forgot to factor devices pre-lollipop, so a section of the code between the if statement was not being executed on pre-lollipop devices. So some views were not being loaded hence the Null Pointer Exception. I still don't know why Ripple Drawable specifically but I will post my code tomorrow so that you can all see.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging can be a pain sometimes and the question above was a result of a simple mistake in my original code. Humans are to err ...

Now to the solution. My initial code was as follows and if you look keenly you will note that the initialization code between the if statement that checks the `Build.Version` does not run if the device is below version 23.

```
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Storage permissions is already available, save profile photo

            initialization();
        } else {
            // Providing additional rational to the user if permission was not granted
            if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Storage permission is needed to save your profile photo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }
```

This is the initialization method. In devices with Android version lower than 23, it did not run thereby triggering the `Could not find class` error. However I still haven't figured out how this is related to Ripple Drawable because am not using Vector Drawables anywhere in my code. So anyone who gets to read this might shed some light onto the cause

```
    private void initialization() {

    hoverView = (View) findViewById(R.id.hoverView);
    hoverView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mExitAppDialog = new HookUpDialog(this);
    mExitAppDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.exit_app_message));
    mExitAppDialog.setOnButtonClickListener(HookUpDialog.BUTTON_OK,
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mExitAppDialog.dismiss();

                    if (WallActivity.getInstance() != null) {
                        WallActivity.getInstance().finish();
                    }
                    sInstance.finish();

                    /* Informing the user, to press back again to exit */
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.string.press_back_again_to_exit,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
    mExitAppDialog.setOnButtonClickListener(HookUpDialog.BUTTON_CANCEL,
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mExitAppDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
    mLlRecentActivity = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llRecentActivity);
    mNoActivitiesView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNoRecentActivities);
}
```

And now to the full code including an else if fix for devices with Android version 23 and below.

```
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Storage permissions is already available, save profile photo

            initialization();
        } else {
            // Providing additional rational to the user if permission was not granted
            if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Storage permission is needed to save your profile photo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 ) {
        // Storage permissions is already available, save profile photo

        initialization();

    }
```

Thanks to @Anurag Singh, I was able to see this after hours and hours of testing and re-testing. Googling and googling.